# Django:How to setup static files in django project

Tags: python, django, static-files

I created a simple project in Django but static files(CSS) not working.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.portfolio),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

HTML file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'portfolio.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

picture of the project directory

[image: picture of the project directory.]

blog is app and my_site is a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "my_site/static")
```

to STATICFILES_DIRS

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "my_site/static")
]
```

OR

place the **static** folder in the root **my_site** folder